# Need help understanding why COUNT DISTINCT is returning an odd result

Tags: oracle11g, count, group-by, distinct

I have a table t1 that contains several fields one being INC_ID.  I was looking to identify and remove the records in t1 with duplicate values of INC_ID.

For background, the other columns in t1 may be the same among records with duplicates of INC_ID and they may not.  e.g.

**INC_ID, VAL1, VAL2**

144345, Red7, ABC

144345, Red7, ABC

144346, Grn2, DEF

144346, Grn2, DEF

---

When I execute

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
```

It returns 10,000 as expected.

When I execute

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
WHERE INC_ID IN
(SELECT INC_ID
FROM t1
GROUP BY INC_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)=1)
```

It returns 9,974.  I am assuming this means I have 9,974 records with a unique INC_ID

When I execute

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
WHERE INC_ID IN
(SELECT INC_ID
FROM t1
GROUP BY INC_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

I get 26 as expected.  An additional check shows that there are indeed 26 records with duplicate INC_ID, there being only 13 unique INC_IDs in the 26 records.

When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INC_ID)
FROM t1
```

I get 9,987.  Not understanding this I thought maybe it was calling the record distinct due to other columns being different even when the INC_IDs were the same.

Then I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INC_ID)
FROM
(SELECT INC_ID
FROM t1)
```

but that still returns 9,987.  Clearly I have some flaw in my understanding of how DISTINCT works.  Can someone explain the why of this to me?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 10,000 values; 9,974 only appear once; the other 26 are two appearances each of 13 values ("there being only 13 unique INC_IDs in the 26 records"). You would get 13 from adding distinct to your third query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INC_ID)
FROM t1
WHERE INC_ID IN
(SELECT INC_ID
FROM t1
GROUP BY INC_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

So you have 9,974 distinct values that appear once, and 13 distinct values that appear twice - which adds up to 9,987. Or to look at it another way, you have 13 values which are duplicates, and 10,000 minus 13 is still 9,987.

All looks fine to me. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a35b4/2) nocking up similar data, which gets the counts you show, and includes the query above and a list of all the rows non-unique IDs.

`COUNT(DISTINCT INC_ID)` is not giving you the count of only those values which are unique within the table - your 9,974 value. It's looking at all of the values but only counting each different value once. If it sees the same value multiple times then it still include that value but will only count it once, however many times it appears. It does not exclude it completely, which you are doing with your `HAVING` clause to get the 9,974 value. Your 13 non-unique values with 26 appearances are still 13 distinct values.

---

Incidentally, here is a [simplistic way to delete duplicates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a35b4/3), but which one of each duplicate pair is kept is indeterminate - if the entire row is identical that doesn't really matter. And it only works for pairs of values, though you could run it multiple times until it finds nothing to delete. If the rows are not identical and you care which is kept then you need to do a little bit more work, but need to define your criteria first.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the explanation, that makes complete sense now.  That is the duplication removal method I went with, the columns that differ in the duplicates aren't important so it works completely.